# Will this TFT LCD work with the Pi?

Tags: screen, composite-video

[image: screen]

I got this screen from Amazon, and I mistook it for having RCA input.

Anywhoo, it came today and I was wondering if it will work with the Pi. A whole caboodle of reviews said it did, but I don't know what to do about the adapter. Should I cut the cable and run wires directly, or should I get an adapter? I'm going to ask this over on http://electronics.stackexchange.com as well to see if they know anything.

[image: plug front]
[image: plug side]

Comment: A picture of the connectors would help us.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm uploading them now. They are from the side and from the front. One side has an arrow on it, just in case that helps. It appears to me that the product image has S-Video, but mine does not.

Comment: Does it have a separate power cable? After searching on Amazon, it seems like you are missing a cable: http://i.imgur.com/9apuiFc.jpg

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking. It came with just the screen, mount, and that cable wired directly into the screen. From what I saw I think I need an adapter. And looking at your image, I'm thinking that too. Thanks, looks like I'm returning that along with the Cobra Gaming mouse that doesn't click. If you would post that as an answer, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a cable:

[image]

Comment: Yup, going to return it as soon as I get the shipping label